# Reformat split continuous CSV into multiple columns

Tags: matlab

I have a strangely formatted CSV file from scientific data "stacks" values instead of appending a column. For example:

```
Parameter : Collision Energy (CE),
Mass =  174,
Max XY = 43,9242

Raw Data : 

0,260
1,268
2,291
3,327
4,366
5,405
Mass =  195,
Max XY = 38,11302

Raw Data : 

0,478
1,498
2,560
3,620
4,707
5,777
Mass =  236,
Max XY = 32,1447

Raw Data : 

0,96
1,100
2,108
3,115
4,122
5,129
```

Instead, I'd like to write a function that would reorganize the data as such:

```
    Mass =  174      Mass =  195       Mass =  236
    Max XY = 43,9242 Max XY = 38,11302 Max XY = 38,11302
0   260              478               96
1   268              498               100
2   291              560               108
3   327              620               115
4   366              707               122
5   405              777               129
```

I haven't gotten very far but so far I've read the file as a table and converted the table to a cell. I wanted to use logical indexing on the cell to search for the string 'Mass' and store the data in a new column inbetween the two indexes but it doesn't work.

Another idea I have is to read row-by-row for string 'Mass'. If true --> store corresponding column 2. Repeat till end of file.

Any ideas how I can do it elegantly that is easy for me to read (just looking for ideas, not expecting full code) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [regular expressions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to read various data types. Read the csv file into a string first using `fileread`function:

```
filetext = fileread('data.csv');
```

Then we can look for individual fields. For example, the numbers for Mass can be extracted as:

```
% read the matching tokens into a cell array
c_mass = regexp(filetext, 'Mass =[\ ]*([\d]+)', 'tokens'); 

% convert the cell array to characters and then interpret as numbers
v_mass = str2num(char([c_mass{:}]));
% [174   195   236]
```

Similarly, for Max XY:

```
c_max = regexp(filetext, 'Max XY =[\ ]*([\d]+,[\d]+)', 'tokens'); 
v_max = str2num(char([c_max{:}]));
% [43        9242;          38       11302;          32        1447]
```

And finally for Raw Data:

```
c_raw = regexp(filetext, '\n([\d]+,[\d]+)', 'tokens'); 
v_raw = str2num(char([c_raw{:}]));
```

Note that this would read the entire raw data into two columns. But you could easily `reshape` it to separate various blocks.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response and it's helped me parse through the data at least to reshape more easily. Is there any resource besides the MATLAB documentation for the regexp function? I've always tried to learn how to utilize this but I really don't understand the formatting. My Matlab education was through the Vanderbilt MATLAB course and they don't do a very good job at teaching how to parse through text like this.

Comment: I am sure there are better resources, but my knowledge of regexp comes mainly from Matlab documentation and some trial and error. Following the examples in the Matlab documentation page is not a bad place to start.